# Log Basic Authentication Requests

Tags: php, authentication, logging

Is there a way to log the basic authentication requests that are being attempted on a PHP page?  I'm trying to determine what the user is sending to help troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you are on apache, check this solution https://serverfault.com/a/475386

.htaccess file:

```
# script that will store invalid login attempts
ErrorDocument 401 /logging.php

AuthName "My Password Protected Site"
AuthUserFile /<FULLPATH>/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user

# Set REMOTE_USER env variable on 401 ErrorDocument
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^401$
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{ENV:REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER}]
Then the actual script that will do the logging:
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])):
    $fp = fopen(MYLOGFILE, 'a+');
    $password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];
    $username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
    $time = date('y-m-d/H:i:s');
    $request = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
    fwrite($fp, $time."\t".$request."\t".$username."/".$password."\r\n");
    fclose($fp);
endif;

ob_start();
header("HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required",1);
header("Status: 401 Authorization Required",1);
echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head><body>
<h1>Authorization Required</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you are authorized to 
 access the document
 requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
 credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
 browser doesn\'t understand how to supply
 the credentials required.</p>';
exit();
```